# How to make Plotly animated chart display all the categories (not only ones present in first frame)

Tags: python, plotly

To illustrate my problem, I use sample Plotly animated chart included on their website:

https://plotly.com/python/animations/

Orginal code:

```
df = px.data.gapminder()
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

It displays all the countries but when we remove data about European countries older than 1970, Europe is not displayed on the legend.

It's even worse when I remove data about Asian countries. It changes frame range even though it has complete data for remaining contintents.

**How to force this chart to include a continent in the Legend always when it appears in at least one frame?**

````
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df.drop(df[(df.continent == 'Europe') & (df.year < 1970)].index) #here I remove data
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rci1.png
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limitations with **plotly** animations in that it is expected dimensions are consistent.   This can be achieved by doing an appropriate *outer join* to ensure all combinations are present.  Taking your sample code as starting point, then use **pandas** to ensure there is dimension consistency before do `px.scatter()`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df.drop(df[(df.continent == 'Europe') & (df.year < 1970)].index) #here I remove data

# ensure all combinations of attributes are present
key_cols = ["continent", "year", "country"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [df[col].unique() for col in key_cols], names=key_cols
    )
).merge(df, on=key_cols, how="left")
# an insignificatly small value
df2["pop"] = df2["pop"].fillna(.001)

px.scatter(df2, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

[image]